# Ruta de imagenes en .net

Tags: c#, .net

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto de `.Net 4.7` sin `MVC`. Tengo dos `Ashx` uno es el updatefile que recoge una imagen y lo graba en el `Sql Server`. Este no tiene problema ya que me hace lo que me tiene que hacer.

El problema es el siguiente: Tengo un `Ashx` `(Imagenes.ashx)` que lo que hace es lo siguiente:

```
Guid id = GetParamsUrl.GetParametroGuid("id", this.requestContext.RouteData.Values, Guid.Empty);
string formato = GetParamsUrl.GetParametroString("formato", this.requestContext.RouteData.Values, "jpg");

if (id != Guid.Empty)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[0];
    Xopity.Imagenes.LogoTipos Logotipos = new Xopity.Imagenes.LogoTipos();
    buffer = Logotipos.GetLogoTipo(id);

    context.Response.ContentType = formato;
    if (buffer != null)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";
        if (buffer.Count() > 0)
        {
            context.Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
    }
}
```

Recoge la imagen de la base de datos y la muestra como imagen.

Despues lo que quiero hacer es crear un `Global.asax` y configurar una ruta, para que sea `www.dominio.es/imagenes/id.jpg` y muestre dicha imagen.

En el `Global.asax` tengo lo siguiente:

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new Route("logotipo/{id}.{formato}", new Imagenes.LogoTipos_route()));
```

Me podriais decir donde tengo el error ya que me dice todo el rato el servidor que la ruta no existe.

Answer (score -1):

No se especificamente si esta sea la solucion ya que no entiendo si las imagenes estan dentro del mismo proyecto o en algun otro servidor. Pero para obtener la ruta de las imagenes dentro de tu aplicacion en el servidor puedes usar esto:

```
var baseStr = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

Este codigo te trae la ruta física de tu proyecto en el servidor usando el **AppDomain**
Ejemplo:

*C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client*

Comment: Guasy las imagenes no estan grabadas en disco estan en base de datos, el ashx lo que hace es leer de la base de datos y mostrar la imagen. El problema es que no quiero una ruta que sea www.dominio.es/imagenes.ashx?id=2

Lo que quiero es que en global.asax configurar una ruta que sea www.dominio.es/imagenes/{id}.{formato} y que dicha ruta lea el ashx muestre la imagen y en codigo se pueda ver www.domini.es/imagenes/1.jpg

No se si me he explicado bien ?